# not seeming to run. well the average module

Tags: c++

I tried running it and it is not doing what it should. I expect 15.53 but get 0. I'm unsure of where the error lies could someone assist me please.

1) Write a main module and in it declare and fully initialize a local array of 15 integer numbers, a local array of 20 characters (not a string), and a local array of 10 floating point numbers. Use different values to initialize each array (don't use 0, blank space, or repeat any value). Also, ensure that the values in each of the three arrays are in sorted order (sorted in ascending order).

2) Write a module called Display that takes an array of integer values and the size of the array as arguments, and then outputs the contents of the array on the screen in a neat format. Each value in the array must be separated by a single space. E.g. 10 20 30...

3) In your main module, call the Display function and use it to show the contents of the 15-value integer array you declared and initialized earlier.

4) Write a module called AVERAGE that takes an array of integer values and the size of the array as arguments, then calculates and returns the average of those values. Feel free to use recursion or iteration in your answer. Also remember to declare your function prototypes.

5) In your main module, call the AVERAGE function and use it to calculate the average of the 15-value integer array you declared and initialized earlier, then display the result. The result returned from the 
function is to be displayed in the main module, not in the function.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void display(int[] ,int );    
float average(int[], int );

void main()
{   
  float avg;

  int lego[15]={2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30};

  char muzik[20]=
    {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j',
     'k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t'};

  float blu[10]={'1.2','1.3','1.4','1.5','1.6','1.7','1.8','1.9','2.0','2.1'};

  display(lego,15);

  average(lego,15);
  avg=average(lego,15);
  printf("Average = %.2f",avg); 
}


void display(int lego[], int Se)
{
    int w;

    for(w=0;w<Se;++w)

        printf("%d ",lego[w]);
}


float average(int lego[], int b)
{
    int s, sum=0;
    float avg;

    for(s=0;s<b;++s) 

    {
        sum+=lego[s];
    }

    avg=sum/b;
    return avg;
}
```

Comment: you experiencing garbage. in garbage out (Maybe you should format your question and actually describe your problem and ask a question)

Comment: when i run it it gives 0.00

Comment: @user2843660: And what output do you expect?

Comment: it is suppose to give 15.53

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is a problem:

```
printf("Average = %.2f",avg);
```

The format string `%.2f` tells `printf()` to expect a `float` value but you are passing an `int`.

You can change `avg` to a `float` variable but you also need to change your `average()` function to perform `float` math and return a `float` result.

Comment: @user2843660: This just shows that `printf()` is a legacy function and is not type-safe. It will try to consume any garbage you pass it. You might consider using a `C++` stream like `std::cout` instead.

Comment: i'm new to programming and my lecturer is moving too fast. the reason i tagged it wit visual c++ is because he makes us use visual to construct or codes

Comment: @user2843660: No problem, the code is plain old `C++` and the tag change may get more people to look at your question. If this helped I would appreciate if you _accepted_ the answer (begging for rep).

Comment: i posted the questions with the code. oh, i also did as u suggested but this time its giving me a whole bunch of numbers

Comment: @Blastfurance im stuck

Comment: @user2843660: I did some fixing and you can see it run [here on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/QBv7XZ)

Comment: @Blastfurance, i took ur advice and it worked. thank u so much

Comment: @Blastfurance can i converse wit u through email?

Comment: @user2843660: Sorry but no. Post another question and give someone else a chance to help :)

Comment: yea, i dnt mind getting other ppl to help me out.